# I need to show related fileds which have many to many relation with same model. Django Rest Frame work

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm trying to create a related product field i've added filed in model with many to many relation and set it to self as i'll select related product manually.

```
class ProductsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    images = ImagesSerializer(many=True)
    color = ColorSerializer(many=False)

    class Meta:
        fields = (
            'url',
            'id',
            "code",
            "sku",
            "title",
            "slug",
            "state",
            "old_price",
            "price",
            "valid",
            "in_stock",
            "category",
            "related_products",
            "color",
            "images",
            "video",
            "description",
            "fabric",
            "model_size_info",
        )
        model = Products
```

I can't refer to same Serializer i need to get product details in the api json. I can't find a way to do that.

Thanks for help guys in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres the solution i've come across.
I created another Serializer

```
class ProductsSerializerTemp(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    color = ColorSerializer(many=False)

    class Meta:
        fields = (
            "color",
            "url"
        )
        model = Products
```

and than i referred it to my original Serializer

```
class ProductsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    images = ImagesSerializer(many=True)
    color = ColorSerializer(many=False)
    related_products = ProductsSerializerTemp(many=True)


    class Meta:
        fields = (
            'url',
            'id',
            "code",
            "sku",
            "title",
            "slug",
            "state",
            "old_price",
            "price",
            "valid",
            "in_stock",
            "category",
            "related_products",
            "color",
            "images",
            "video",
            "description",
            "fabric",
            "model_size_info",
        )
        model = Products
```

I pretty much did the job i'm not sure if this is the best solution but it worked very well.

Answer (score 1):

**Method-1:** Override the **`__init__()`** method

```
class ProductsSerializer_Temp(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    images = ImagesSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        fields = (
            'url',
            'id',
            "title",
            "images",
        )
        model = Products


class ProductsSerializer(ProductsSerializer_Temp):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields.update(
            {"related_products": ProductsSerializer_Temp()}
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all, I think you should use something like [DynamicFieldsModelSerializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dynamically-modifying-fields) to prevent the recursion

```
class DynamicFieldsModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    A ModelSerializer that takes an additional `fields` argument that
    controls which fields should be displayed.
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Don't pass the 'fields' arg up to the superclass
        fields = kwargs.pop('fields', None)

        # Instantiate the superclass normally
        super(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if fields is not None:
            # Drop any fields that are not specified in the `fields` argument.
            allowed = set(fields)
            existing = set(self.fields)
            for field_name in existing - allowed:
                self.fields.pop(field_name)
```

then, You can use `SerializerMethodField` and also specify the fields you want  in relevent products('don't pass `related_products` to prevent the recursion  '):

```
class ProductsSerializer(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer):
    images = ImagesSerializer(many=True)
    related_products = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_related_products(self, obj):
        return ProductsSerializer(obj.related_products, many=True, fields=('url', 'id', "title", "images")).data


    class Meta:
        fields = (
            'url',
            'id',
            "title",
            "related_products",
            "images",
        )
        model = Products
```

Comment: I tried but this is going on recursion. i think i forget to mention related products will also have related products in it so i need to be care full in that section.

Comment: I can also use depth attribute but i need colors for those products as well which i'm already getting in current code I've so depth needs to be 2 which is quite use less and will take longer to respond wanna keep it minimum and effective.'

Comment: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fields' it's not useable

Comment: pay attention to `class ProductsSerializer(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer):` your serializer should inherit from `DynamicFieldsModelSerializer`

Comment: I got the solution for this. I created another Serializer and set it to retrieve the information let me put that in answer.